# communicating with other process in C

Tags: c

i want to send message(for example:"hi") from my c proccess to my winforms application,

so this is my options:

1(It took me an hour to get, I think it will help many others):
my idea is to make the winform window title as a pipe to communicate (using user32.dll functions)

C code:
(by using windows.h?)

```
changeWindowTitle(winformhandle,"hi"); //Change Other Window title To Hi
```

Vb.Net code (kind of title listener):

```
Dim last As String = getTitle(me.handle)
While true
dim t as string = getTitle(me.handle)
if t <> last then //Check if this application title is changed
last = t
GotMessage(t)
end if
system.threading.thread.sleep(2)
Loop
```

another good option:
Use socket (by localhost)
server = my winforms application
client = c proccess

another option (yes..not recomended):
use file
c proccess writes "hi" to text file and when not in use winforms application reads all text

another bad option (Here you depends on the Internet):
c proccess using kind of webclient/inet to send parameter to php script hosted on server:

```
web.com/s.php?msg=hi
```

winforms application is cecking every 3 seconds for new messages

 
So you can even rename a file to "Hi" if its short message and check for changes...
you can use memory address, you can use pixels, you can use something called "c pipes", you can use netcat , you can use nemsise.exe, you can even build application for communication,
but this is not the reason that i'm talking about communication,
**the big question is:

what is the best communication method? (fastest+best because of many other reasons)

and how it can be done with c (1 example = 100000 words)? (I'm really new in c programing!)**

Comment: Google IPC (Inter Process Communication) and you will find more data and opinions than you can shake a stick at.  Also lots of examples.  In addition to those you mentioned, there are semaphores (not really useful here), message queues (more useful), Signals (potentially useful depending on what you are trying to do exactly) and more.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: I have the source code of an old game, this game developed with c, and borland 3.1 is the only compiler that can compile it (i tried every existed compiler), so what i want to do is: send message from the game (by C) to my winforms application without using windows SDK (only borland can compile :/)

Comment: Look at message queues.  It would be good for two way communication.  Signals may also be good if you want to map every input.  Alternatively if you have the sourcecode you could convert it to a new language as you are probably redoing a lot of the graphics anyway

Comment: ok,thanks i will try it again, anyway if you will find example of short way to communicate with c it's will help me alot, i'm very new c programer

Comment: recoding it will give you better performance, more practice with both languages, and will be less of a headache than anything else

Comment: you know what, it's a very good idea =),I will think about it. thank you!